# Want to keep 91 disabled using AngularJs in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, function

HTML FILE

```
 page.html

<form autocomplete="off" name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && submitRequest();"> 

<input type="tel" 
       minlength="10" 
       maxlength="10" 
       name="userPhone" 
       class="form-control height40"
       ng-model="user.phone" 
       ng-click="insertCounryCode();"
       placeholder="* Your 10 digit Mobile Number"  
       ng-disabled="disabledVal"
       required>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default request_call_submit form-control">Request Callback</button>
</form>
```

Now JS FIle

```
// app.js

// Controller

  $scope.user = {};


    $scope.insertCounryCode = function () {
        $scope.user.phone = "+91";
    }

    $scope.submitRequest = function () {
        // Submitting user response
    }
```

I am able to add +91 when the user clicks on this input field but I want this field to be disabled so that user don't able to change +91.
Only the user can change only the enter mobile number only

Will any one tell how Can I do that using AngularJs ?

Comment: What I will suggest you that put a label of +91 in front of input field instead of adding +91 text in input field

Comment: Then how can I show the same infront of the input field so that the user won't see like that it is different from input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a fiddle for this requirement. We can do this through CSS. Please check the fiddle. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZLcg/489/). Thanks. Let me know if this is ok for your requirement. Adding my CSS and HTML here

```
.input-box { position: relative; }

input { display: block; border: 1px solid #d7d6d6; background: #fff; padding: 10px 20px 10px 30px; width: 195px; }

.unit { position: absolute; display: block; left: px; top: 10px; z-index:  9; }



<div class="input-box">
  <input value="" autofocus="autofocus"/>
  <span class="unit">+91</span>
</div>
```

Comment: but when I do this placeholder shifts to right. I want to start placehoder from left

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/k1vv55ty/2/

```
<input type="text" value="+91" class="disabled-input" disabled>
<input type="text" class="enabled-textbox">
```

CSS

```
 .disabled-input {
    width: 26px;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    margin-right: -4px;
    padding: 1px 0;
}

.enabled-textbox {
   border: 1px solid #999;
   border-left-width: 0;
}

.enabled-textbox:focus {
  outline-offset: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

Here I have override focus css.